# Qt opengGL implementation

Tags: qt, opengl

How Qt's Opengl widget works? Is it a software-only implementation or it relies on the configuration of the platform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a Qt widget that embeds an OpenGL context of the native platform - i.e. You're using the OpenGL libraries/setup on your platform - which doesn't have a lot to do with Qt